# C# can't see text when updating text box

Tags: c#, textbox

I was wondering if someone could help me with a little issue I'm having. I'm trying to update a textbox from another class but the text is not showing up on in the textbox even though it is being sent as I have printed it to the screen.

The code I'm using is below:

Program.cs

```
namespace Search
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]

        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();

            try
            {
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {

            }
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        public static readonly Form1 MainLogWindow = new Form1();
    }
}
```

HexToASCII:

```
public class HexToASCII
{
    Output o = new Output();

    public void hexToAscii(String hex, int textBox)
    {
        //Convert the string of HEX to ASCII
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string hs = hex.Substring(i, 2);
            sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)));
        }
        //Pass the string to be output
        string convertedHex = sb.ToString();

        Program.MainLogWindow.UpdateTextBox(convertedHex);    
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
    private delegate void NameCallBack(string varText);
    public void UpdateTextBox(string input)
    {  
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            textBox2.BeginInvoke(new NameCallBack(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { input });
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + input; 
        }
    }
```

I have tried to run it using a new thread ThreadStart ts = delegate()... but I'm unable to get the textbox to update. Sorry I'm very new to c#, could someone please explain the issue so I can understand it and learn for next time. Many thanks :)

Comment: Refresh the text box after setting its value

Comment: Looks like you have two completely separate instances of `Form1`. Try out following, instead `Application.Run(new Form1());` write `Application.Run(Program.MainLogWindow);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
static void Main()
{
    ...
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

public static readonly Form1 MainLogWindow = new Form1();
```

You're creating two forms: one of them is being shown (with `Application.Run`) but you're changing the contents of the text box on the other one:

```
Program.MainLogWindow.UpdateTextBox(convertedHex);
```

You haven't shown how you're calling `hexToAscii` in the first place - personally I would try to avoid having static references to GUI elements like this, but you *could* get your code to work just by changing your `Main` method to use:

```
Application.Run(MainLogWindow);
```

Comment: Ha ha, now you have pointed this out to me it's quite obvious and a stupid mistake! Silly newbies! Many thanks though that seems to have solved the issue, I will mark you as correct when it lets me :)